# Where to find an "auth_nonce" for Facebook Developers

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

May I know where to find the "auth_nonce" for the facebook graph API.

Currently, I wanted to do the re-authenticate for my facebook-connect and it requires me to enter the "auth_nonce".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook [re-authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/) has some information about the `auth_nonce`

To make a new NONCE

`$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection`

Answer (score 0):

You generate it, and should never use the same value twice (n once).

Comment: I've read the definition which its requires 64-bits of random string to prevent replay attacks.

Which mean I do need a function to keep generate it for me?